# Segmentation fault in C++ program that scans a directory

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

This is my program, but I'm getting "Segmentation fault" messages without any warnings when compiling.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <cstring>

int is_file(char* path) {
    struct stat s;
    if (( stat(path,&s) == 0 ) && ( s.st_mode & S_IFREG )) return 1; else return 0;
}

int main()
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    char path[] = "../";
    if ((dir = opendir (path)) != NULL) {
      /* print all the files and directories within directory */
      while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
            char* name = strcat(path, ent->d_name);
            if (is_file(name)) printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
      }
        closedir (dir);
      } else {
        /* could not open directory */
        perror ("");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
     }

}
```

I think that this is because of `is_file()` reference on line 20, but I don't know why and how to fix it.

Comment: Don't stack your statements up like that. Bugs hide in clutter.

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step ⏯️ carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: PSA: In C++ there is a strong convention to make function calls like `f(...)` not `f (...)`, the latter of which reads as a flow-control structure like `if (...)` or `while (...)`.

Comment: The variable `path` has only capacity for 3 characters.

Comment: Why not use [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem)?

Comment: `char* name = strcat(path, ent->d_name);` is wrong, `sizeof(path)` is too small (leading to buffer overrun).

Comment: strcat: The behavior is undefined if the destination array is not large enough for the contents of both src and dest and the terminating null character.

Comment: @tadman: There are so many different styles used in C++. What bothers me more is that OP's style is inconsistent.

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Why does your code look like "C"? Where did you learn C++ from? As said for C++ there is [std::filesystem](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem). All this strcat, strcopy code is not needed, just use std::string and its operations.

Comment: @Jarod what bothers me is the "C"-ness of it all : the raw pointers, the memory leaks and general resource unsafety of the code.

Comment: Good sources to learn C++ from : [a recent C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) or from [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) that site is decent and pretty up to date.
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) for reference material (and examples). When you have done all that keep using [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with the latest best practices since C++ keeps evolving.

Comment: @OP `#include <string>` -- You didn't use anything associated with `std::string`, which is the purpose of this header file.  If you had done this, you more than likely wouldn't have an issue since `strcat` would not have been used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`strcat()` doesn't work the way you think it does; in particular, it can only write more chars into already-allocated space within an array; it can't resize `path[]` larger to store the additional chars.  `path[]` only has 4 bytes of storage allocated for it, so when you try to `strcat()` to path, you write past the end of that array, and invoke undefined behavior, causing a segmentation fault.

Since you're using C++, the fix is straightforward:  use `std::string` to store your variable-length string data rather than a C-style char array:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <cstring>

int is_file(const char* path) {
    struct stat s;
    if (( stat(path,&s) == 0 ) && ( s.st_mode & S_IFREG )) return 1; else return 0;
}

int main()
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    const std::string path = "../";
    if ((dir = opendir (path.c_str())) != NULL) {
      /* print all the files and directories within directory */
      while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
            const std::string name = path + ent->d_name;
            if (is_file(name.c_str())) printf ("%s\n", ent->d_name);
      }
        closedir (dir);
      } else {
        /* could not open directory */
        perror ("");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
     }
}
```

Comment: `path[]` has 4 bytes of storage (`{ '.', '.', '/', '\0' }`, everything else you said looks correct.

Comment: I have fixed that error, thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Even with this fix, there's still a logic error.  `path` is only going to be correct for the first file.

Comment: It helped, thank you!

Comment: @MarkRansom AFAICT `path` never changes in my version.  I've tagged it `const` to verify.

Comment: Of course, I assumed that `path` was going to hold the actual full name as it did in the question.  Didn't read the code closely enough to realize you were creating a second string variable `name`.  Sorry to bother you.